# Hold Elasticsearch document frequency constant as index changes

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I'm using Elasticsearch to retrieve XML documents by terms. I have multiple indexes, one for each day. I have a large collection of documents that is, in some sense, representative. The document frequency of several terms varies from day to day.

The mathching I'm doing depends on inverse document frequency of terms. I'd like to not use the IDF of the indices I'm searching, and instead use the IDF based on the large, representative set. Is there a straightforward way to do this without writing custom scoring functions for large, complex queries?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way.

FWIW , To access and use IDF , you need to write a [custom script Engine](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/modules-scripting-engine.html) in elasticsearch, and probably use that engine based script for sorting.